# Use Linq to search through table for items from a custom class

Tags: c#, linq

My code below works but I'm trying to find out how to optimize this and/or make it faster by changing it to one line because currently it performs a query on the database table once per loop and this seems to take forever

The custom class and sql table both have the same exact names as you can see. The queryList is a list of the custom class.

```
foreach (var item in queryList)
{
    var query = context.DataTable.Where(i => i.ValueName == item.ValueName && i.Symbol == symbol && i.Days == item.Days).ToList();

    if (query.Count() > 0)
    {
         context.DataTable.RemoveRange(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the members of `queryList` inside the `Where`:

```
var query = context.DataTable.Where(i => i.Symbol == symbol && queryList.Any(item => i.ValueName == item.ValueName && i.Days == item.Days)).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error at your line of code when I try to run it. MultipleRegressionInfo is the name of the custom class btw

Unable to create a constant value of type 'AdminClient.MultipleRegressionInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with some datatypes and where the `AdminClient` and `MultipleRegressionInfo` apply.

Answer (score 0):

If your `queryList` is not a huge list, this may work:

I assume `symbol` should actual be `item.Symbol`. If that's the case, try this:

```
var items = queryList
    .Select(item => item.ValueName + "," + item.Symbol + "," + item.Days.ToString())
    .ToList();
var query = context.DataTable
    .Where(i => items.Contains(i.ValueName + "," + i.Symbol + "," + i.Days.ToString());
```

The idea is to build a list of strings that LINQ to SQL can convert to `WHERE x IN (str1, str2, str3)` clause.

Comment: I'm getting unexpected $ character errors and I can't run this code

Comment: @user3610374, I changed the code to not use string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` to fetch all data at one trip to database:

```
var query = context.DataTable.Where(x => x.Id == 0);
foreach (var item in queryList)
    query = query.Union(context.DataTable.Where(i => i.ValueName == item.ValueName && i.Symbol == symbol && i.Days == item.Days));

var allData = query.ToList();
if (allData.Count() > 0)
    context.DataTable.RemoveRange(allData);
```